# automatic formatting for placeholders

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I'm completely new to python and struggling with the following: I'm trying to write a program that takes an user entered standard text including 'placeholders' like 'last_name','first_name', etc. The available placeholders are  the headers of a pandas dataframe and can differ each time. What I wanna do is to create an individual text per entry in the dataframe with the standard text, but the placeholders should be replaced with the individual name. What I have so far is the following:

```
indiv_text = input('Please enter your standard text here. Use {'header'} for the individual placeholder', )
text = []

for i in dataframe.index:
    text.append(indiv_text.format(last_name = dataframe['last_name'][i],first_name = dataframe['first_name'][i], etc. manually entered for all headers))
```

This works out but as I do not know the headers I have to create the part within .format() automatically. I do not know how many of the possible headers the user is going to use, so I have to enter each header as placeholder. I expected the following to work, but it doesn't:

```
text.append(indiv_text.format(header = [dataframe[header][i] for header in list(dataframe)]))
```

Can anyone help me out? I'm using Python 3.6.5.